# How to manipulate node server response according to percentage of the requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How would I make a node.js server which returns "hello" on 20% of the requests and "hello world" on the remaining?

> Basically, how would we manipulate the server so that we can change
> the response according to the percentage of the requests?

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: May I ask what is the real world problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm not solving a real world problem, actually this is an interview question which I was not able to answer. Obviously, got rejected. I want to know how can it be done.

Comment: Requests from same IP address ?

Comment: No, they can be from anywhere.

Comment: well, suppose you want to show hello to 20% of users. declare a counter variable with an initial value of `0`, then increment the counter on every request and reset after every 10 requests. Then if the counter value is <= 2 return "Hello" otherwise return "hello world".
:D :D

Comment: if we don't want to use a counter variable?

Comment: actually, you can't predict how many requests is coming in next minute, so unless you know the exact amount of incoming requests you can't do that

Comment: Or, you can define array from 10 elements with 2 items of "hello" and 8 of "hello world" and get element from this array with random index

Comment: Is it supposed to be random, and just 20% average? Or should it be some specific 20% (of users, of ip addresses, of something else)?

Comment: it is random, just 20% of any requests